# Packer pipeline is failing due to restart command in PowerShell provisioner

Tags: windows, powershell, packer

I have integrated packer with azure DevOps pipeline. Currently this packer is being utilized for patch deployments through SCCM. But there are few patches which need VM to reboot for corresponding patches installation, If we add reboot command[Restart-Computer] within PowerShell script which is been called by packer provisioner, packer pipeline is failing out. Can someone help here please!

Comment: You can background the `packer build` process in the pipeline.

Comment: What is the output when you say " packer pipeline is failing out"?